Could Puzzling be exempted from some punctuation rules?
Question titles automatically have certain rules imposed on them, whose goal is to fix some common grammatical and stylistic solecisms. (It looks bad to end a sentence with several exclamation marks!!!, etc.)
However, some of these are a poor fit for the Puzzling site, because most of its questions are puzzles rather than people actually seeking help, and a good puzzle title is not necessarily the same thing as a good question.
There's more detail of this in this question on puzzling.meta and the (excellent) sole answer to it, but here are some brief examples:

"Find the next element in this sequence: 1, 2, 3, ?"

At present this will have the space before the "?" automatically removed, which is not an improvement.


"When in Rome ..."

Of course this isn't a question and it would be a terrible title for a question on, say, travel.stackexchange.com. But it would be fine as the title of a puzzle. At present it would turn into "When in Rome."; again, not an improvement.



Any of the following would (I think, and I expect most active Puzzling participants to think) be an improvement:

Just turn off the trailing-punctuation stuff for Puzzling.
Turn it all off except that spaces before final punctuation are still removed unless that punctuation is all question marks, and multiple exclamation marks are still collapsed to a single exclamation mark.
Leave it all on except that strings of "." and "?" are no longer collapsed and spaces before final question marks are no longer removed.

If there isn't any substantial difference in implementation effort, the second of those is probably preferred.
A bit of precedent: the no-spaces-before-final-punctuation rule, being inappropriate en français, was disabled for french.stackexchange.com. So it seems that there's at least some flexibility here...

This should be asked on Puzzling Meta if there's no other site on which this is being requested on. Stack Exchange staff members do check per-site metas for feature requests, and the normal process of tagging them as [tag:status-review] also works on them.

As you are a moderator on Puzzling, you should either retag the question you linked to with the status-review tag, or you should post this question on your site's meta and tag it with status-review, citing the community consensus achieved in that same question. I would migrate this question back to your site, but I think you'll have a better idea about how to move forward with this request than I would. That said, given this is about Puzzling specifically and no other sites, I've closed this as relating to only one specific site.

I wonder more broadly - could a site request 'different'/relaxed rules for things like this?

Oops, my apologies; I evidently had the procedure wrong and will proceed accordingly.

@JourneymanGeek French Language got an exception made, so it wouldn't be without precedent.
